# How to generate UTID based on UUID in ruby?

Tags: ruby, uuid

I need to generate UTID in ruby. Here's what I found in one documentation.

> UTID - Many services use uniquely-generated ID, called Unique
>   Transaction IDs (UTIDs). These IDs are based on standard UUIDs, but
>   modified to be more human-readable. The process of creating a UTID is
>   as follows:
>
> 1. Generate a Version 4 (Random) UUID
> 2. Convert the UUID to a binary representation of 16 bytes
> 3. Encode the binary UUID using base32
> 4. For readability, the UTID may have a dash `"-"` inserted every 5 characters with a final group of 6 characters.
>
> The specific character set for base32 encoding must be
>   `0123456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ`.  An example for converting UUID
>   `d0ab7ada-1a1e-4893-8e1e-4ab07da05dc3` is UTID
>   `T2NQN-PGT3S-4973G-Y9AR7-V82XRC`.

(I'm using the example from the above documentation for checking my results. But they never match.)

The problem is that I can't recreate these steps exactly. I'm not sure how to implement 2nd and 3rd steps. For the first step I use this:

```
SecureRandom.uuid.delete('-')
```

How to implement all other steps?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Your line doesn't even work and doesn't seem to be much help according to the 4 points you mentionned.
`undefined method 'remove' for "b91542f8-4252-47d0-9fb7-6cdcbe18ff32":String (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @AlexisDelahaye Sorry. I was in rails console when I was testing that code. I changed it on `SecureRandom.uuid.delete('-') `. It works in `irb`